# find rank of a student in a table that its contained students point

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

ihave a simple table that it has some record that There have been several records about students. i want determine rank of each student base on point. i use following query. its ok  when i get query for all of student but when i search student by name or family all the student have  1 rank and i know its normal but i have any  solution for it. i want to gain real rank  when  i search a student by name  in each class do u know applied solution ?

```
Select username ,average,[fname],[lname],point, Rank() over(order by point desc) as    'ranking' from karbar where (username=@username) order by point desc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use subquery.

```
SELECT * from
(Select username ,average,[fname],[lname],point, 
 Rank() over(order by point desc) as  'ranking' 
 from karbar order by point desc) t
WHERE username=@username
```

Comment: thanks for reply  but it has  following error:The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified.

Comment: you could remove `order by point desc` after `from karbar` and try again since you are filtering a username. I am more familiar with mysql and not familiar with tsql.